# mouseClicked method

Tags: java, swing

The below code is placed in a method . But it seems too large and I would like to shorten it. Is there a better way to do what it does?

```
ImageIcon switchoffIMG = new ImageIcon("switch1.jpg");
ImageIcon switchonIMG  = new ImageIcon("switch2.jpg");

JLabel switch1 = new JLabel(switchoffIMG);
JLabel switch2 = new JLabel(switchoffIMG);
JLabel switch3 = new JLabel(switchoffIMG); /* Will add these into different JPanels */

boolean switch1state, switch2state, switch3state;
switch1state = switch2state = switch3state = false;

switch1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(switch1state == false)
        {
            if((e.getX() >= OFFBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= OFFBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= OFFBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= OFFBUTTONDOWN))
                switch1state = true;
        }else
        {
            if((e.getX() >= ONBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= ONBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= ONBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= ONBUTTONDOWN))
                switch1state = false;
        }

        paintStuff();
    }
});

switch2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(switch2state == false)
        {
            if((e.getX() >= OFFBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= OFFBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= OFFBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= OFFBUTTONDOWN))
                switch2state = true;
        }else
        {
            if((e.getX() >= ONBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= ONBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= ONBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= ONBUTTONDOWN))
                switch2state = false;
        }

        paintStuff();
    }
});

switch3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(switch3state == false)
        {
            if((e.getX() >= OFFBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= OFFBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= OFFBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= OFFBUTTONDOWN))
                switch3state = true;
        }else
        {
            if((e.getX() >= ONBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= ONBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= ONBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= ONBUTTONDOWN))
                switch3state = false;
        }

        paintStuff();
    }
});
```

**Additional information (if required):**

```
public void paintStuff()
{
    if(switch1state)
    {
        switch1.setIcon(switchonIMG);
        left.add(bulb1);              //Add image to JPanel
    }else
    {
        switch1.setIcon(switchoffIMG);
        left.remove(bulb1);           //Remove image from JPanel
    }
    if(switch2state)
    {
        switch2.setIcon(switchonIMG);
        mid.add(bulb2);               //Add image to JPanel
    }else
    {
        switch2.setIcon(switchoffIMG);
        mid.remove(bulb2);            //Remove image from JPanel
    }
    if(switch3state)
    {
        switch3.setIcon(switchonIMG);
        right.add(bulb3);             //Add image to JPanel
    }else
    {
        switch3.setIcon(switchoffIMG);
        right.remove(bulb3);          //Remove image from JPanel
    }
    repaint();
}
```

and

```
final static int OFFBUTTONTOP   = 75;
final static int OFFBUTTONLEFT  = 30;
final static int OFFBUTTONRIGHT = 65;
final static int OFFBUTTONDOWN  = 115;

final static int ONBUTTONTOP   = 35;
final static int ONBUTTONLEFT  = 25;
final static int ONBUTTONRIGHT = 60;
final static int ONBUTTONDOWN  = 75;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean switch1state, switch2state, switch3state;
```

These three variables are a good start to write everything three times. But then it gets too long... Numbered variables are usually a code smell. Wouldn't an array do?

```
switch1state = switch2state = switch3state = false;
```

Useless, just drop it.

```
        if(switch1state == false)
        {
            if((e.getX() >= OFFBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= OFFBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= OFFBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= OFFBUTTONDOWN))
                switch1state = true;
        }else
        {
            if((e.getX() >= ONBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= ONBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= ONBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= ONBUTTONDOWN))
                switch1state = false;
        }
```

After splitting the "if-else" into two "if"-s and a simple reordering the conditions gets clearer:

```
        if((e.getX() >= OFFBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= OFFBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= OFFBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= OFFBUTTONDOWN))
            if(switch1state == false) {
                switch1state = true;
            }
        if((e.getX() >= ONBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= ONBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= ONBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= ONBUTTONDOWN))
            if(switch1state == true) {
                switch1state = false;
            }
        }
```

and we see that's repetitive without any reason. Moreover, spacing is wrong and things like `switch1state == false` should be written as `!switch1state`. But we don't need it, anyway.

```
        if ((e.getX() >= OFFBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= OFFBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= OFFBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= OFFBUTTONDOWN)) {
            switch1state = true;                
        } else if ((e.getX() >= ONBUTTONLEFT && e.getX() <= ONBUTTONRIGHT) && (e.getY() >= ONBUTTONTOP && e.getY() <= ONBUTTONDOWN))
            switch1state = false;
        }
```

But wait... your rectangles seem to overlap, so it's wrong. Then let's resort to my basic rules:

- never copy stuff
- if you ever do it, never copy long stuff

So what about

```
if (!switch1state && isInRectangle(ON_RECTANGLE, e)) {
    switch1state = true;
} else if (switch1state && isInRectangle(OFF_RECTANGLE, e)) {
    switch1state = false;
}
```

There's a class `Rectangle` and it has a method to determine if a `Point` is in it, which you can use.

With an array you can do simply this (the annotation come from Lombok and does exactly what it states; just in case you want to do it manually)

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private final int index;

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!switchstate[index] && isInRectangle(OFF_RECTANGLE, e)) {
                switch1state = true;
        } else if (switchstate[index] && isInRectangle(ON_RECTANGLE, e)) {
                switch1state = false;
        }
        paintStuff();
    }
}
```

### paintStuff

```
if(switch1state)
{
    switch1.setIcon(switchonIMG);
    left.add(bulb1);              //Add image to JPanel
}else
{
    switch1.setIcon(switchoffIMG);
    left.remove(bulb1);           //Remove image from JPanel
}
```

This can be shortened a bit like

```
switches[0].setIcon(switchstate[0] ? switchonIMG : switchoffIMG);
if (switchstate[0]) {
    leftMidRight[0].add(bulb[0]);              //Add image to JPanel
} else {
    leftMidRight[0].remove(bulb[0]);           //Remove image from JPanel
}
```

using three more arrays

```
Button[] switches[] = {switch1, switch2, switch3};
JPanel[] leftMidRight = {left, mid, right};
Icon[] bulb = {bulb1, bulb2, bulb2};
```

and now it's ready for a loop.

### constants

```
 final static int OFFBUTTONTOP   = 75;
```

Wedonotwriteconstantslikethis. Ihopethereasonisclearnow. Use

```
 private final static Rectangle OFF_RECTANGLE = ...
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I feel so dumb not thinking about arrays. Thanks a lot! One doubt. Why is `switch1state = switch2state = switch3state = false;` useless? (In my original program, `switch1state, switch2state, switch3state,switch1,switch2,switch3,switchoffIMG,switchonIMG` are fields of my class)

Comment: @CoolGuy In Java all fields get initialized to some form of zero (`0`, `0.0`, `false`, or `null`).

Comment: Can `ImageIcon` or `Icon` be directly added to a `JPanel`? Or is it better to stick with the `JLabel`s as in my code?

Comment: And [here is my full code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93500/switch-bulb-gui-program). I hope it looks good.

Comment: @CoolGuy I wasn't here. You can't add icons directly, so I guess using labels is fine. I'd probably handle the bulbs just like the switches, i.e. a label with bulbOn or bulbOff (empty) icon. You've got already a review on your new code and I agree with janos' objections, but in any case,  it's a huge improvement.